# Async Generator Function to Generator Function?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a websocket running as another task.
This listening task uses a generator function to stream audio from a microphone. It is blocking the websocket task, as a result the websocket task is failing to ping pong the server and we get a disconnect.

the audio_generator has to be a async generator because otherwise it would block the websocket.
so if I make it async it says async generator is not iterable.

This is due to the generator expression don't support async generators?

Original Code before async changes:

```
 requests = (speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
 for content in audio_generator) 
           // requests is a standard generator
responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
```

So I convert the generator expression to this

```
def responses_gen(audio_generator, speech):
    for content in audio_generator:
        yield speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
```

And use it like so

```
 audio_generator = stream.generator()
 requests = responses_gen(audio_generator, speech)

            responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
```

This fails to work.

None Exception iterating requests! meaning that it likely failed to understand what I gave the streaming_recognize function

Please note that the audio_generator uses a while True loop with a yield and a asyncio.sleep(0.01).

Is there a good way todo this? I was considering using a thread then having the results shipped to queue to be picked up by the websockets task, but I would like to avoid that.
If this could interfere with latency of the audio stream then I guess that would be a good idea.

Comment: Your problem is not that generator expressions don't support async generators, but that `streaming_recognize` is not async. If you use asyncio, you must use an asyncio-compatible library. Another option is to run the recognizer in a separate thread and use `asyncio.call_soon_threadsafe` to communicate with asyncio, e.g. via a queue. Google  `call_soon_threadsafe` on StackOverflow for examples.

Comment: Thats exactly what I found thank you!